# How to do constructor injection for a single parameter out of many?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt for dependency injection. I want to do constructor injection in adapter for a single parameter. Below is my adapter class:

```
public class MovieHorizontalListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val adapterDataList: List<Any>,
    private val dataType: String = "Movie",
    private val userUtils: UserUtils
): RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {
   // adapter related code
}
```

I only want to inject the `userUtils: UserUtils` parameter to be injected. Is this possible?

I have already created the below for UserUtils class:

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserUtils(prefsManager: PrefsManager): UserUtils {
        return UserUtils(prefsManager)
    }
```

I am having trouble injecting into to adapter class. What are the possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: What trouble have you been having?

Comment: I want to do constructor injection but only for a single parameter userUtils  out of others

Comment: Ah I see, your question seemed to focus on an issue with injecting adapters specifically. You can used assisted injection for this, although I might not recommend injecting adapters at all, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: What I would recommend is to do the field injection in the fragment or activity for the UserUtils class then just pass it to adapter constructor.